# Assigning objects dynamically from array - best practice - nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

What is the best practice to assign objects dynamically from the contents of an array. This is the way I'm doing it right now and it works, but it seems a bit dirty. Is the better approach to make a class like object? How would I do it in that case?
example:

```
var names = ["test", "foo", "bar"];
var dict = {};
// init values
names.forEach(function(n){
   dict[n] = {};
   dict[n].property1 = false;
   dict[n].property2 = true;
   dict[n].property3 = "";
});
```

Comment: Seems fine, but you're not really using the array values for anything? You could probably reduce it as well -> `names.reduce(function(a,b,i) { return a[i]={p1:false, p2:true, p3:""},a }, {})`

Comment: @adeneo That comma trick isn't really necessary unless it's an arrow function. `a[i]={p1:false, p2:true, p3:""};return a` is just as short, and less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create factory function to create object from array. Inside that function you can use for example [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to initialize object:

```
var makeMyDict = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(r, n) {
        r[n] = {
            property1: false,
            property2: true,
            property3: ""
        };
        return r;
    }, {});
}

var names = ["test", "foo", "bar"];

var dict = makeMyDict(names);
```

Comment: C'mon, man, how could you pass up an opportunity to name that function holdMyDict? Son, I am disappoint.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems fine. You can always use `reduce` to build an accumulated object.

```
const props = {
  property1: false,
  property2: true,
  property3: ``
};

const names = [`foo`, `bar`, `baz`];

const dict = names.reduce((a, x) => {
  a[x] = {};
  for (let p in props) a[x][p] = props[p];
  return a;
}, {});

// Or using object spread (requires babel at the moment)
const dict = names.reduce((a, x) => (a[x] = {...props}, a), {});

console.log(dict);

{ foo: { property1: false, property2: true, property3: '' },
  bar: { property1: false, property2: true, property3: '' },
  baz: { property1: false, property2: true, property3: '' } }
```

Comment: I like this answer as well. The properties are like a `struct`. Looks very clear. Thanks